# Testing dsc pull server via Invoke-RestMethod unexpectedly closes

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-dsc

I am setting up a DSC HTTPS Pull Server and am testing the service.
In the browser I can access the service with the following URL

```
https://dsc.mydomain.com:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc/$metadata
```

However the same URL using PowerShell fails.  Why?

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://dsc.mydomain.com:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc/$metadata -Verbose
```

This is the error in PowerShell:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://dsc.mydomain.com:8080/PSDSCPullSe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using https, you'll also have to use a signed certificate, so unless that's part of $metadata, that's probably what's causing your issue.